# If $10$ gifts are to be distributed among $3$ friends, how many distributions are possible? What if each friend should receive at least $3$ gifts?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> If $10$ gifts are to be distributed among $3$ friends, how many distributions are possible? What if each friend should receive at least $3$ gifts?

For part ii, I was thinking of doing $10C3 \cdot 7C3 \cdot 4C3$ first then the final gift left can be distributed to anyone so we multiply by $3$ to get $50400$.

Comment: The answer given is 12600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If $10$ gifts are to be distributed among $3$ friends, how many distributions are possible if each friend should receive at least $3$ gifts?

If $10$ gifts are distributed among three friends and each friend receives at least three gifts, then one person receives four gifts and the others each receive three.  There are three ways to select the person who receives four gifts, $\binom{10}{4}$ ways to select the gifts that person receives, $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to select the gifts the younger of the two remaining friends receives, and the other friend must receive all of the remaining three gifts.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{10}{4}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}$$
admissible ways to distribute the gifts.

**Note:**  Your method counts each distribution four times, once for each of the $\binom{4}{3}$ ways of designating three of the four gifts the person who receives four gifts as the three gifts that person receives.